# Client and Server communication using Javascript and websockets

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I am a  beginner in Javascript and would like to know procedures and starting codes to connect client side and server side using JS and websockets.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262543/what-are-good-resources-for-learning-html-5-websockets) seems like a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Try socket.io: http://socket.io/#how-to-use
Easier is if you have nodejs on server side